# Laravel can't add new column to table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm want to add new enum column `status` to `customers` table. But when im trying to run migrations I'm get this errors:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `customers` where `customers`.`deleted_at` is null and `status` = 1)  

  [PDOException]                                                                     
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'
```

**Migration:**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $enum = [
            'activated' => 1,
            'deactivated' => 0
        ];
        $table->enum('status', $enum);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('status');
    });
}
```

Comment: That error is not caused by the migration code.

Comment: That error is not caused by this particular migration. Maybe you have migrations running in the wrong order and another one depends on this one or something in your startup code is running that query before the migration is actually ran.

Answer (score 0):

Your enum value should not be an associative array

```
$enum = ["activated","deactivated"];
```